# How to fix closure "expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body" when using enumerated().map

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, inout

I have the following Swift code which uses `enumerated().map` to index my `modeStrings`:

```
let modeNames = [
            "Rest: ",
            "Misbalanced: ",
            "Left Charged: ",
            "High Voltage: ",
            "High Temperature: ",
            "Low Temperature: ",
            "Low Voltage: ",
            "Hibernation: ",
            "Over Discharge Current: ",
            "Ship: "
        ]
        var modeStrings = [
            deviceData.restMode,
            deviceData.misbalancedMode,
            deviceData.leftChargedMode,
            deviceData.highVoltageMode,
            deviceData.highTempMode,
            deviceData.lowTempMode,
            deviceData.lowVoltageMode,
            deviceData.hibernationMode,
            deviceData.overDischargeMode,
            deviceData.shipMode
        ]
        
        let indexAndNum = modeStrings.enumerated().map { (index: Int, element: inout String?) in
            let value: String
            if Int(data[28 + index]) == 1 {
                value = "On"
            } else {
                value = "Off"
            }
            let formattedString = (modeNames[index] + value)
            element = formattedString
        }
    }
```

My problem is I get an error `Contextual closure type '(EnumeratedSequence<[String?]>.Element) throws -> ()' (aka '((offset: Int, element: Optional<String>)) throws -> ()') expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body`

This error goes away if I remove the `inout` keyword but then I get this error: `Cannot assign to value: 'element' is a 'let' constant`.

`element` is referring to my `modeStrings` which is of the type `[String?]`. How can I assign a value to `element` without using `inout`? Or am I just using `inout` incorrectly?

Comment: What do you want to do here? Do you want a new array with `formattedString`s as the elements, or do you want to modify `modeStrings`? If you want to modify `modeStrings` then using `map` is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I want to modify the values in modeStrings. What can I use instead of map?

Comment: This entire snippet feels... off. Can you give an example of desired output? And why is this check so arbitrary?: `if Int(data[28 + index]) == 1`. What does `data` look like?

Comment: `data` is an array of `UInt8` values. Nothing more than that. The values in question as indicated by `data[28 + index]` are only ever going to be 1 or 0 so I need all values that come through in that range that have the value of 1 to be "On" and for 0, "Off".

Comment: `deviceData` is a public struct that I am using to temporarily hold all the values (stored as `String`). So, essentially I want the On's and Off's to be stored in my struct.

Comment: Do you have control over `data`? This feels like some restructure would solve the entire issue. For example, why can't data be a json representation of the values? Why are the modeNames and modeStrings arbitrary arrays rather than a model object?

Comment: @TJOlsen I am receiving the array over bluetooth low energy connection. The only control I have is after I receive the data. As of now, I am unaware of any way to represent the data as json but if there's a way, I would like to know about it!